# React Navigation Custom Header and Custom Back Button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation. I created a custom header component myself. I call this component into other components. But the back button I use on the header doesn't work for other components. How can I add this to the react navigation stack.

`navigation.back()` or `navigation.navigate('Home)`

I get an error when I write.

Comment: pass navigation props in component

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you not transmit navigation? print `console.log(navigation)`. And you can use `navigation.goBack()`

Comment: No, just print  console.log(navigation)

Comment: navigation is not defined error. Do I need to stack it for this?

Comment: You not get `navigation` check above if you have navigation

Comment: I am trying to operate on a component that is not specified in the stack. therefore it does not receive the navigation information. Is it possible to do without specifying?

Comment: I don't understand you. What does not mean without specifying?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `function LeftMenu(props) { return ( <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName={props.route}  drawerContent={(props) =>  <Custom_Side_Menu {...props}/>} drawerContentOptions={{activeTintColor: 'rgb(219,218, 218)'}}> <Drawer.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen}/> </Drawer.Navigator> ); }`

And you can get `navigation` in `props LeftMenu`